# KeychainWrapper as a substitute for NSUserDefaults for storing highScore

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

Hi I created an app and use to store highScores in `NSUserDefaults` and would load the `highScore` everytime the game is launched using this code:

```
var highScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highScore")
```

Then Ive heard that it would be easily modified and so I thought I would use keychain. I dont know much about keyChain then I found [SwiftKeychainWrapper](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper) that looked rather easy to implement. I am using this code

```
var highScorestring: String = KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("highScore")!
var highScore = Int(highScorestring)
```

However, everytime the app launches I get a `found nil while unwrapping Optional value` which I suspect is due to the first line of code that force unwraps `highScorestring`.

I guess Keychain does not really retain the data after it quits? I tested it without the force unwrap but instead did a `let if` and `highScore` always is 0 because the code is not run. Can some one explain a little why this happens?

Comment: Your keychain code is for reading the stored value. Obviously there won't be a score the first time your app runs. You need to handle that case.

Comment: Man Im a dumbass. Long day at Starbucks. Works perfectly now! Thanks! (Love your work btw)

Comment: Note that modifying keychain is not particularly harder than modifying NSUserDefaults. Maybe a tiny bit harder because it doesn't sync quite so obviously via iTunes, but not much of a challenge for a jailbroken phone.

Comment: Noted. What would be better then? Not just for highscores but for unlocking IAP features as well?